# Why does SQL Server query works differently on different servers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which is behaving differently when run against two databases.

I have copied a staging database locally and am using it to debug my code.

Here's the query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ........, ACs.LastName
Bs.Name AS BranchName, .....
......
...... ) LEFT JOIN CompanyTrove 
AS Bs
ON .........................
............................
Order BY ACs.LastName,Bs.BranchName, ..... ASC
```

CompanyTrove table has no column called BranchName. So, this fails on my local copy of my database. But when I run the same query against the actual database it runs just fine even though the CompanyTrove table on the database does not have the BranchName column (It is the same table of course).

Any ideas on what I am missing ?

Comment: Is Bs.Name actually returning data when you run the query?

Comment: `BranchName` is just an alias.  the column name is `Name`.  As for why it's working in one database and not the other, we can't say without any error details.

Comment: Yes, Bs.Name is a valid column name.

Comment: @sstan. I got that ..... the key thing stumping me is that in one case Bs.BranchName is working correctly (i.e. not throwing an error) and in another case it throws an error : Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Invalid column name 'BranchName'.

Comment: `AS BranchName` just changes the name that is returned in result set. The column it is looking for is the first part `Bs.Name`, so no problem there.  Maybe the exact error message you are getting would reveal more.

Comment: You can't reference an alias like this `Bs.BranchName` such as in the Order By clause.  **Unless maybe you have a named subquery.  There's more going on here than you are showing.**

Comment: @AaronLS yes you can on older versions.

Comment: You can't have a column alias prefixed by the table alias in the `ORDER BY` clause in [2005 or later.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240807(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith,bjones : Maybe that is the key. JBrooks below probably pointed to that as my version (2014) is VERY different from the staging one which is at 2008. Please see below for the listed versions.

Comment: @user1554876 you need to look at database compatibility level as well as version. SQL Server 2008 version supports databases back to SQL Server 2000 compatibility (Compatibility Mode = 80). You can see this in database properties in SSMS.

Answer (score 2):

See

[Behaviour Changes to Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2005](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143359(SQL.90).aspx)

Specifically the Order By Clause section.

The SQL Server 2000 behaviour was

> Column names in the ORDER BY clause are resolved to columns listed in
>   the select list, regardless if they are qualified. For example, the
>   following query executes without error:
>
> ```
> USE pubs
> SELECT au_fname AS 'FName',
>   au_lname AS 'LName'
> FROM authors a
> ORDER BY a.LName
> ```
>
> SQL Server ignores the qualifier a in the ORDER BY clause and resolves
>   the column name LName to the select list.

So I presume that you were trying this on a database in 2000 compatibility mode when it worked without complaint.

Comment: Thank you ! That is the answer. I will modify the queries (in code) as removing the prefixes will make it work in both the newer and older versions of the SQL Server.

Comment: @user1554876 If this database was running in 2000 mode you might have other issues too. Such as deprecated outer join syntax that won't run in modern versions.

Comment: Agreed. The app using this database on staging is in classic ASP (nuff said) :)

Answer (score 1):

Run this to make sure the versions match:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

Then run this to see which options are different:

```
sp_configure
```

Comment: On my local machine sp_configure says : Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) 
 Apr 20 2015 17:29:27 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) On the staging one (which is VERY old) : Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64) 
 Jul  9 2008 14:17:44 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2) (VM)

Comment: @user1554876 Also look to see if any of the properties from sp_configure set Compatibility level.  If this is set, it will behave like that version instead of its true version.  Might be time to upgrade your servers?

Comment: `sp_configure` sets instance level properties not database level properties such as compatibility level.

Comment: @MartinSmith right, he should look at both.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `BranchName` is just an alias, your `order by` clause should not prefix `BranchName` with `bs.`

It should instead be:

```
Order BY ACs.LastName,BranchName, ..... ASC
```

Comment: Yes, I have already seen that it works that way. Unfortunately, the sql query is constructed in code. Thus it executes perfectly on the staging one but not locally when executing against the newer version ! I am now making the changes as removing the prefix makes it backward compatible as well. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

can you just try bs.* and see if that works.  Maybe bs.Name really doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the table alias from the `ORDER BY`...

`BranchName` is the alias for your actual column - `Bs.Name`

```
Order BY ACs.LastName,BranchName, ..... ASC
```